# Deploy container on Azure with Terraform from private DockerHub repo

Tags: azure, docker, terraform

I am deploying an application to Azure from a container and an image stored in DockerHub. When I deploy the repository in the DockerHub is public so I can easily deploy it. However, I would like to have the repository private and still be able to deploy it. Can I somehow pass my credentials for DockerHub to the terraform configuration?

At the moment this is what I am using to deploy the container. It all works but I would really like to have the repo as private.

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "cg" {
  name                = "mycontainer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  dns_name_label      = "mycontainer"
  os_type             = "Linux"

  container {
    name   = "mycontainer"
    image  = "myuser/myimage:tag"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Charles Xu's response is perfectly correct; you must provide the `image_registry_credential` to access private DockerHub repository. However, we continued to have troubles with that, and regardless of whether we checked the tag to `:v1`, `:0.0.1`, or even `:latest` version, nothing was conclusively ending. As a result, we found that our Docker Hub server address was actually incorrect. It is specified that the server url should be the url of the server on which we are now working. We chose `hub.docker.io` instinctively (from the web address). However, this was not working properly, and therefore we discovered in a forum somewhere that `index.docker.io` is the correct URL to use for dockerHub private repository.

Then, if you have @Charles Xu's response and your docker hub repo URL is `hub.docker.io` in your terraform file's server variable, change it to `index.docker.io` and tada!

By combining this response with that of Charles Xu, we arrive at the following:

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "cg" {
  name                = "mycontainer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  dns_name_label      = "mycontainer"
  os_type             = "Linux"

  container {
    name   = "mycontainer"
    image  = "myuser/myimage:tag"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }

  image_registry_credential {
    username = "xxx"
    password = "xxx"
    server   = "index.docker.io" // for docker hub private repository
  }
}
```

Comment: Can confirm that for private Docker Hub images, the specified server should be "index.docker.io" and the image should be suffixed with the tag id. Had been struggling to get this working having switched from public to private image, but now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the attribute [`image_registry_credential`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_group#image_registry_credential) of the `azurerm_container_group` with your private registry credential, something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "cg" {
  name                = "mycontainer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  dns_name_label      = "mycontainer"
  os_type             = "Linux"

  container {
    name   = "mycontainer"
    image  = "myuser/myimage:tag"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }

  image_registry_credential {
    username = "xxx"
    password = "xxx"
    server   = "server_url"
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error `riginal Error: Code="InaccessibleImage" Message="The image 'myuser/myimage:tag' in container group 'mycontainer' is not accessible.`. I am using the correct credentials and `hub.docker.com` as the server url

Comment: @everspader Probably the image name is not right. You can try to check if you can login the private registry locally and pull thei mage.

Comment: Image name is correct. I am the owner of the repo where the image is stored so I'm playing around with it and when I have the repo public without the `image_registry_credential` block, it's possible to pull the image but not when the repo is private and the block is on with the credentials

Comment: @everspader Can you give the screenshot of the image with tag in your private registry?

Comment: @everspader So you set it as `image=everspader/myimage:0.1`? All the things work fine on my side.

Comment: no not yet. I still get the same error that the image cannot be accessed.

Comment: @everspader Can you the real Terraform code with setting the credential?

Comment: @everspader Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @everspader any news? we got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Image needs to be:
"serverurl/username/myimage:tag"